# Invert controller on Portal 2

Tags: portal-2

I've recently started playing with a controller, but I haven't been able to invert the camera control (right joystick).

Some information:

- Running on Windows 10 but streamed to Linux
- Controller is some wired logitech.
- There is an option for invert mouse but it doesn't do anything.
- I'd be happy to go into some configuration file, but I found there are a lot of them that pertain the controller, so I don't know which one to modify.

Any help with this?

Comment: The easiest way is in your controller's config, if you can make use of the Logitech gaming software. If it works you can remap any button you want to whatever you want. Please add some more info to your question if you're able to use the Logitech software (or whatever software is shipped with the controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Keyboard/Mouse in the Options menu, there's a Controller menu (for some reason I didn't see it before). Inverting x and y are there.

There are also options to somewhat change what each button and axis do.